# Não consigo instalar o PHP-FPM no Ubuntu

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, php-fpm

Quando eu tento rodar o comando `sudo apt install php5.6-fpm`, eu estou recebendo a seguinte mensagem:

> Alguns pacotes não puderam ser instalados. Isto pode significar que
>   você solicitou uma situação impossível ou, se você está usando a
>   distribuição instável, que alguns pacotes requeridos não foram
>   criados ainda ou foram retirados da "Incoming".
>   A informação a seguir pode ajudar a resolver a situação:
>
> Os pacotes a seguir têm dependências desencontradas:
>    php-fpm : Depende: php7.0-fpm mas não será instalado
>   E: Impossível corrigir problemas, você manteve (hold) pacotes quebrados.

Porém eu não quero instalar o `php7.0-fpm`, eu quero apenas instalar para a versão `php5.6` do PHP.

Eu também tentei rodar o comando `sudo apt install php5.6-fpm`, porém recebo outra mensagem de erro:

> O pacote php5.6-fpm não está disponível, mas é referenciado por outro pacote.
>   Isto pode significar que o pacote está faltando, ficou obsoleto ou
>   está disponível somente a partir de outra fonte
>
> E: O pacote 'php5.6-fpm' não tem candidato para instalação

Em me lembro de ter conseguido instalar o PHP-FPM para a versão 5.6 do PHP.

Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

**Observação**: Não sei ainda como resolver isso (e se isso é o problema), mas no meu Ubuntu, sempre que atualizo o PHP, ele instala "de brinde" as versões `7.0` e `7.1`. Portanto, eu tenho esses três instalados na minha máquina!

Comment: As versões atuais do Ubunto não estão mais dando suporte ao PHP 5.6, apenas o 7, para instalar ele você vai quer que buscar um repositório alternativo.

Comment: Não pode ser via ppa ?

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php    ////
  sudo apt-get update    ////
sudo apt-get install php5.6-fpm

Comment: @AnthraxisBR posta aí, deu certo :)

Comment: @AnthraxisBR eu acho que isso aconteceu porque eu atualizei a distro do ubuntu para a 17, ele deve ter removido as PPA antigas!

Comment: @WallaceMaxters eu não atualizei o meu ainda, não sabia que perdia as ppas, bom saber pra eu não atualizar kk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As versões mais recentes do Ubuntu não oferecem suporte ao PHP 5.6 nativamente, apenas ao 7.0 +, mas você ainda pode instalar as dependencias e componentes via PPAs.

Para o php-fpm:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install php5.6-fpm
```

Comment: Deu certo aqui. Parece que ao instalar a nova versão do Ubuntu as configurações que eu já tinha feito para esse repositório foram removidas.